# What does "odds" mean in Path of Exile?

Tags: terminology, path-of-exile

I am a beginner. I saw this word on a [Reddit /r/pathofexile post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/9nz5ur/poe_crafting_probabilities/).

I've searched on google for a long time, but I still don't know its meaning well. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a special term for Path of Exile.

They mean "[odds](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/odds)", as in probability.
The "odds" are the chances of something happening.

When they say "What are the odds of XYZ happening" they are asking "what are the chances of XYZ happening?".

In your specific example they appear to be discussing the probability of getting certain results from crafting.